# Скрипт с циклом по подразделам реестра

Tags: vbscript

Здравствуйте Уважаемые программисты!

Подскажите пожалуйста, как на vbs прописать цикл по всем "профилям" (Default, nGeoniCS, ... как на рисунке) в разделе "Profiles"?

Цикл нужен для того, чтобы в каждом "профиле" изменить значение параметра "\IO\SaveProjects\DefaultFormatForSave".

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: [Здесь развернуто с примерами на VBS](https://www.script-coding.com/WMI_StdRegProv.html)

Comment: Спасибо посмотрю.